# css image not showing

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, image, path

I am trying to load a image to the division below in asp.net mvc view. If I assign the background color in it it shows the color but image.

```
 <div class="pic">afssadf</div>
```

here is my css

```
.pic
{   
    background:url(Images\c.jpg) center top no-repeat;       
}
```

The image is not showing in the division. what is going wrong in above code;

Comment: have you checked the dev tools for a 404 error? Have you given the `<div>` a size? (width, height, etc?) Not really enough info here in the example code to accurately diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
.pic
{   
    background:url(../Images/c.jpg) center top no-repeat;       
}
```

This generally happens because the path you specify in the url is wrong. One easy way to debug this is with Firebug in Firefox. Select the element that should have the image and try different URLs till you get the correct one.

Comment: Yes... you even confused me! :) I had to look in one of my CSS files to confirm that... hehehe